# Why am I getting a "The connection was reset" error when trying to run my Django application on a Docker container?

Tags: mysql, django, docker, containers

I'm trying to containerize my Django app, and always seem to keep running to issues with mysql connection (or permissions?) issues. I still don't really understand what's going on during this process, and I keep running into the same general error.

My config files are at the end of this post. I'm in my project root (where my docker-compose.yml resides), and I try running
`docker-compose up --build`. But, I get this error :

```
sportsbet-web-1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
sportsbet-web-1  | Exception in thread django-main-thread:
sportsbet-web-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
sportsbet-web-1  |     self.connect()
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
sportsbet-web-1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
sportsbet-web-1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
sportsbet-web-1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
sportsbet-web-1  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 130, in Connect
sportsbet-web-1  |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in __init__
sportsbet-web-1  |     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
sportsbet-web-1  | MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)")
sportsbet-web-1  |
sportsbet-web-1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
sportsbet-web-1  |
sportsbet-web-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
sportsbet-web-1  |     self.run()
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
sportsbet-web-1  |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
sportsbet-web-1  |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
sportsbet-web-1  |     self.check_migrations()
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 486, in check_migrations
sportsbet-web-1  |     executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
sportsbet-web-1  |     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
sportsbet-web-1  |     self.build_graph()
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 220, in build_graph
sportsbet-web-1  |     self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
sportsbet-web-1  |     if self.has_table():
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
sportsbet-web-1  |     with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
sportsbet-web-1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
sportsbet-web-1  |     return self._cursor()
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
sportsbet-web-1  |     self.ensure_connection()
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
sportsbet-web-1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
sportsbet-web-1  |     self.connect()
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
sportsbet-web-1  |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
sportsbet-web-1  |     self.connect()
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
sportsbet-web-1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
sportsbet-web-1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
sportsbet-web-1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
sportsbet-web-1  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 130, in Connect
sportsbet-web-1  |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
sportsbet-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in __init__
sportsbet-web-1  |     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
sportsbet-web-1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)")
```

OK, I've encountered this before, but always keep forgetting how I resovled it in the past. But I suspect it has something to do with my **settings.py**, which is

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('MYSQL_DATABASE'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('MYSQL_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 3308
    }
}
```

I suspect the error is coming from my msyql database settings in **settings.py**, in particular the `HOST`. So, instead of using whatever address the service `db` is on, I try changing the value of `HOST` from `db` to `172.17.0.2` (the Docker internal IP address).

I get this from the container output:

```
sportsbet-web-1  | Performing system checks...
sportsbet-web-1  |
sportsbet-web-1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
sportsbet-web-1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
```

So, I'm thinking, "OK, cool. Maybe I finally got it to work." I check to see if the containers are up and running using `docker-compose ps` and sure enough I get this:

```
NAME                COMMAND                  SERVICE             STATUS              PORTS
sportsbet-db-1      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   db                  running             0.0.0.0:3308->3308/tcp, :::3308->3308/tcp
sportsbet-web-1     "python manage.py ru…"   web                 running             0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp
```

I open a browser and type `localhost:8000` in the address, but I get run into this error:
[image]

And this is the point where I get stuck. WHERE AM I GOING WRONG??!?

### My Config Files

I have the following config:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER="milhouse"
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD="vanhouten"
      - MYSQL_DATABASE="sportsbet_dev"
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="password"
    volumes:
      - test_vol:/var/lib/mysql/
    ports:
      - 3308:3308
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  test_vol:
```

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('MYSQL_DATABASE'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('MYSQL_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 3308
    }
}
```

...and **Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=1
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=vanhouten
ENV MYSQL_USER=milhouse
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=sportsbet_dev

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app/
```

Comment: You're connecting to `'PORT': 3308`, but MySQL's port is usually 3306.  You should change this port number to match.  Connections between containers don't use `ports:` at all, so they always use the standard port for the destination service.  The second `ports:` number also needs to be the normal port number 3306, or you can remove `ports:` for the database entirely.

Comment: Yes, thank you this worked! For some reason, I was thinking that mapping port '3308:3308' meant MySQL would be also running on port 3308 in the containerized app, but I guess that's not what it does. Thanks again!